# View controller dismiss issue

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, dismiss, dismissviewcontroller

I am setting up a new application which have a firebase authentication

While you are registered user there is no problem with you to create and post add (Item) so other people can see it. BUT if you are not logged in user it will show you a Log IN pop up! WHICH HAVE A DISMISS button!

I tried to create an if statement for example

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if segue.identifier == "itemToAddItemSeg" {
            let vc = segue.destination as! AddItemViewController
            vc.category = category!
            }
        }

    private func showItemView(_ item: Item) {

        let itemVC = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "itemView") as! ItemViewController
        itemVC.item = item

        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(itemVC, animated: true)  
    }

    //Mark: Load items
    private func loadItems() {
        downloadItemsFromFirebase(category!.id) { (allItems) in
            self.itemArray = allItems
            self.tableView.reloadData()   
        }
    }

    private func showLoginView() {
        let loginView = UIStoryboard.init(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "loginView") 
        self.present(loginView, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }  
}
```

Which code need to be implemented? - so if when my showlogin pops up!
someone will press dismiss button it will not proceed to the `AddItemViewCotroller`

moreover it will stay on the same page in `itemViewController`

Comment: If you are showing a login view and the user presses *Dismiss*, it should NOT proceed into the app as they would not be logged in. Most of the code in the question is unrelated to logging in or what happens when the dismiss button is pressed. Can you clarify what you're asking or what the issue is? maybe include the code from the loginViewController, dismissButton Action?

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5**

```
dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
```

> Dismisses the view controller that was presented modally by the view controller.

I can’t tell how you are calling your dismiss function based on your provided code, but an example of implementing the dismiss method:

```
func dismissButtonTapped() {
   dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil) 
}
```

Again, not sure how you are calling your function, but the example above should be enough to guide you in the right direction.

This will dismiss the showLoginView and keep the user on the itemViewController.

Since you presented your loginView morally, this should do the trick.

Check out the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621505-dismiss) on the `dismiss(animated:, completion:)` method for more details.

Comment: in the cocoTouchCLass which i am using there is no Button outlet! My question is not how to input DISMIS button its when showlogin pops up! someone will press dismiss button it will not proceed to the AddItemViewCotroller, moreover it will stay on the same page in itemViewController

Comment: When someone is pressed on dismiss function i need it to stay on the same page (ItemViewControler) instead of transitioning to AddItemViewController

Comment: I’ve edited my answer with a better explanation. Should help.

Comment: Edited my answer. Should be enough to guide you in the right direction. Give it shot, let us know if it works.

Comment: Inside your dismiss button's IBAction, call `dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)` as suggested by @swiftymaxx

Comment: Guys The dismiss its not a problem i did a dismiss function! the problem is that when its dismissing its not doing an any trick its still on the same AddItemViewController!

Comment: I think the problem is in transition because my transition method is even if i will showloginviewpopUp its transitioning anyway! its totally avoid if statement!

Comment: The structure is like that i believe when the ad button pressed which was showing a pop up window! 1) the transition is happening ! 2) after transition no matter logged in user or not! its happening anyway! 3) and already when the user is on AddItemViewController the ShowLoginPopsUp! and when the user press the cancel button the show login button is dismissing with the exact code which u provided! and it shows an AddItemViewController because it transited already! but i want to show the ItemViewController!

Comment: Please edit your question and provide your transition method. It’s hard to debug without seeing the code.

Comment: Maybe i need a return function somewhere!?

Answer (score 0):

As i said earlier the problem was with a transition i am really sorry if i  implemented the wrong code! The issue was in the place where i was implementing the code if Muser.curentUser() != nil

there was a better place when someone will press the done button they will ask them are they are registered users or no? adding a show login view popup in other place solved the issue sorry guys!! thank you you are the best and really good people because you tried to help me! thank you so much!